# OpenGL floating point precision

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, precision

I am working on a project to migrate from legacy/immediate OpenGL to modern OpenGL (core profile). In the legacy OpenGL implementation, we used double precision, i.e. we made use of `GL_DOUBLE` in `glVertexPointer` and we used `glLoadMatrixd`, etc. However, in modern OpenGL, only OpenGL/GLSL 4.0+ supports double precision.

How does old OpenGL support double precision while newer OpenGL doesn't?
How does legacy OpenGL handle double precision while most graphics cards don't even support double precision?

I couldn't find any information on the internet or some answers were too old.

Do current graphics cards support double precision? Should I use OpenGL 4.0?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if `GL_DOUBLE` didn't actually equate a C++ `double` in almost every case.

Comment: I am not sure, but I'd expect that old graphic cards used half-float by default. And GL_DOUBLE would mean regular float. But I only speculate. Graphic cards support `double` but they tend to have a lot less cores that can perform double computations making it almost useless as performance would take a huge hit.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `GL_DOUBLE` should be equal to c++ `double` as the legacy OpenGL works with C++ `double`. However, modern OpenGL (not OpenGL 4.0+) doesn't have APIs for double, i.e. `glUniform` doesn't accept double, and you can't define doubles in you shaders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does old OpenGL support double precision while newer OpenGL doesn't? How does legacy OpenGL handle double precision while most graphics cards don't even support double precision?

It doesn't what you think it does. That you can use doubles as vertex attributes does not imply (and never did) that the GL implementation will do calculations with that precisions - GPUs never did that. The data is converted to single precision in any case. Same for the matrices -  the matrices which were sent to the GPU were never double precision in legacy GL, no matter if you used `d` or `f` suffix when specifying the data CPU-side.

Just with more recent GPUs, double precision became available in the shader cores, and modern GL 4.x allows you to use that *for the first time*.

Also note that lots of real-world consumer GPUs have some insane low double precison ratio like 1/32 of the FP32 performance, so you better think twice before using that. For graphics, you seldom will need that. And the fact that your previous code worked with legacy GL proved that you did not need the precision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So graphics cards internally use single precision even when I call `glVertexPointer` with `glm::dvec3` vertices?

Comment: Yes! You'd need GL4.something and `glVertexAttirbLPointer` for that (note the `L` in the function name, the "L" stands for "double")

Comment: @TaoChen: "*So graphics cards internally use single precision even when I call glVertexPointer with glm::dvec3 vertices?*" Not just that. If you try that, the system basically has to, *on the CPU* read your vertex data and convert the doubles to floats, since the hardware can't actually read them. Doing that would kill your performance.

Comment: "*For graphics, you seldom will need that.*" Indeed, the most obvious place you would use it (positions in VS's) wouldn't actually help, since `gl_Position` is a single-precision vector. And even if it wasn't, the hardware that consumes it *certainly* can't handle double-precision values. Nor can the depth buffer.